# If two iBeacons are too close to eachother, could their signals get confused for one another?

Tags: signal, bluetooth, low-power, bluetooth-low-energy, signal-integrity

I have a simple question that I can't find the answer to. I am testing an app with some iBeacons, and I observe that one of my iBeacons never begins to range...the region is monitored, its just not being detected. When I look at console output the other beacons get detected, and then a few seconds later, another beacon gets detected, but it has the same UUID/major/minor/identifier values as one of the other locations already detected.

So all but one of the beacons get recognized and their states get determined. Then it appears that one of the beacons that has already been determined, gets determined again (same info). These beacons are somewhat close together (about a meter apart in x, y but on different floors (2nd floor and 3rd floor), and I'm wondering if one beacon signal could override another...which would be why I am seeing the info for one of the beacons twice. Otherwise I'm not sure why I can't detect this one beacon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iBeacon seems to be based of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

As discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209945/why-do-2-bluetooth-peripherals-not-interfere-mouse-and-keyboard), Bluetooth devices cannot normally interfere with each others. They simply "wait" for their turn.

In your case, I guess they are "beacons", which are connecting and disconnecting frequently to devices to send data. Your issue might be that you are misunderstanding one beacon for another ? Or it might be software related.

Comment: thanks...so it seems like it is something in my code...if you want to see code i posted here too...just incase it is software...maybe you can see something wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073422/if-two-ibeacons-are-close-together-can-one-signal-override-another-on-the-way-t

Comment: I'm not experienced with iOS, sorry. Can't help you now, good luck :)

Comment: i figured out it is just a crappy beacon...i moved it closer (next to me) and it started working basically...(after changing the major/minor values..even though there shouldn't have been a conflict)...i have another question though...if i have two beacons at 0db and one beacon at 6db (the crappy one) will that mess up the proximity readings?

Comment: The claims in this answer are almost entirely wrong.  Beaconing is not a connected operation, but rather a unidirectional transmission, and collisions are a very real possibility.  The way it is supposed to work is that you often enough luck out in being listening when the beacon transmits and no other beacon is also transmitting a strong enough signal to interfere.  Generally that works, but with a very large number of them it wouldn't.